# Default values for Vue component props & how to check if a user did not set the prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

**1.** How can I set the default value for a component prop in Vue 2? For example, there is a simple `movies` component that can be used in this way:

```
<movies year="2016"><movies>



Vue.component('movies', {
    props: ['year'],

    template: '#movies-template',
    ...
}
```

But, if a user doesn't specify the `year`:

```
<movies></movies>
```

then the component will take some default value for the `year` prop.

**2.** Also, what is the best way to check if a user did not set the prop? Is this a good way:

```
if (this.year != null) {
    // do something
}
```

or maybe this:

```
if (!this.year) {
    // do something
}
```

**?**

Answer (score 339, accepted):

`Vue` allows for you to specify a default `prop` value and `type` directly, by making props an object (see: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation):

```
props: {
  year: {
    default: 2016,
    type: Number
  }
}
```

If the wrong type is passed then it throws an error and logs it in the console, here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cexbqe2q/

Comment: What about second question (this is more JavaScript question): what is the best way to check if a user did not set the prop?  Is this a good way: `if (this.year != null)`  or maybe this: `if (!this.year)` or? Thanks!

Comment: If you set a default value the prop will always be set unless you set the default to `null`. If that is what you need to perform some other logic `if (this.year != null)` or `if (!this.year)` is the way to go.

Answer (score 51):

This is an old question, but regarding the second part of the question - how can you check if the user set/didn't set a prop?

Inspecting `this` within the component, we have `this.$options.propsData`. If the prop is present here, the user has explicitly set it; default values aren't shown.

This is useful in cases where you can't really compare your value to its default, e.g. if the prop is a function.

Comment: This was a great strategy in Vue 2. Unfortunately `this.$options.propsData` is removed in Vue 3. Is there another way to check if a prop has been explicitly passed in?

Answer (score 8):

Also something important to add here, in order to set default values for arrays and objects we must use the default function for props:

```
propE: {
      type: Object,
      // Object or array defaults must be returned from
      // a factory function
      default: function () {
        return { message: 'hello' }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 6):

Worth mentioning, that you also can add a custom validator function to every prop like this, to ensure the passed value matches your components specific requirements:

```js
props: {
  year: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
    validator (value) {
      return value > 2015
    }
  }
}
```