# Use default value if prop argument is null

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this simplified avatar component:

```
<template>
  <img :src="src">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Avatar',
  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
      default: '/static/avatar-default.png'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Let's say I fetch some user data from my API and it contains no avatar URL. In such case I want this component to use the default value but it only seems to work when passing `undefined` to it, but `undefined` is not valid in JSON so I cannot return that from the API response.

Is there a way to realize what I want by passing in `null` or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default values for Vue component props & how to check if a user did not set the prop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365741/default-values-for-vue-component-props-how-to-check-if-a-user-did-not-set-the)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would make a computed property based on the `src` prop value that will return a default value if the `src` is `null`:

```
<template>
  <img :src="source">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Avatar',
  props: {
    src: { type: String }
  },
  computed: {
    source() {
      return this.src || '/static/avatar-default.png';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also explicitly pass `undefined` as prop if `src` is `null` and you'd rather want the component to handle default values.

```
<template>
   <img :src="src || undefined">
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
<template>
  <img :src="src || '/static/avatar-default.png'">
</template>
```

And personally, I would keep the default value for the prop in addition to coercing null values to the default value.

As far as I know, you cannot achieve what you want through the prop definition.